# .less styling not applied when appended to <head> with jquery but .css works

Tags: jquery, html, css, less, bootstrap-table

I'm appending a `.less` file to my `<head>` section after a table was loaded by jquery. The `.less` file is loaded in my browser but the styling is not applied. When change something in my `.less` file and save it in visual studio, the styling is applied correctly. I switched the `.less` file with a `.css` file and stuff works on first try. 
Can someone explain this to me or give me a reference, please?

Comment: You need to load .css files in your html docs only, not .less files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see how the CSS ties in with LESS in the Inspect Tool in Chrome, for example, then you would need to use source maps.

Read more on [tutsplus](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-less-and-the-chrome-devtools--net-36636).